# Exchange 2013 DAG over 2 Subnets replication failure

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, dag

I have 2 Exchange 2013 Standard servers on two different subnets. One is on our local network and the 2nd is on our Cloud provided by our ISP. Adding the 2nd server to DAG went well and seeding the database over was ok too, however, the 2nd server won't failover.

When I try to make the new server as primary and mount the DB I got the following error:

```
An Active Manager operation failed. Error: The database action failed. Error: Operation failed with message: MapiExceptionCallFailed: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1105) Diagnostic context: Lid: 65256 Lid: 10722 StoreEc: 0x451 Lid: 1494 ---- Remote Context Beg ---- Lid: 45120 dwParam: 0x361A1FD Lid: 41344 Guid: 8f10e3e2-f5f8-4c0a-b109-643620473fbc Lid: 35200 dwParam: 0x313C Lid: 50464 StoreEc: 0x451 Lid: 46144 dwParam: 0x361A50A Lid: 34880 dwParam: 0x361AD48 Lid: 59009 StoreEc: 0x451 Lid: 53912 StoreEc: 0x451 Lid: 1750 ---- Remote Context End ---- Lid: 1047 StoreEc: 0x451 [Database: Users, Server: helios.xyz.co.uk]
```

I have done Test-ReplicationHealth command and I get the following error:

```
[PS] C:\Users\exadmin\Desktop>Test-ReplicationHealth

Server          Check                      Result     Error
------          -----                      ------     -----
HELIOS          ClusterService             Passed
HELIOS          ReplayService              Passed
HELIOS          ActiveManager              Passed
HELIOS          TasksRpcListener           Passed
HELIOS          TcpListener                Passed
HELIOS          ServerLocatorService       Passed
HELIOS          DagMembersUp               Passed
HELIOS          MonitoringService          Passed
HELIOS          ClusterNetwork             Passed
HELIOS          QuorumGroup                Passed
HELIOS          FileShareQuorum            Passed
HELIOS          DatabaseRedundancy         *FAILED*   There were database redundancy check failures for database 'Ma...
HELIOS          DatabaseAvailability       *FAILED*   There were database availability check failures for database '...
```

General info:

Helios (server 1): 192.168.0.20
Winterfell (Server 2): 192.168.78.190
DAG IP: 192.168.0.200
Windows 2012 r2 on both and Exchange 2013.
There is only 1 NIC on each server (Currently the cloud environment cannot give us a 2nd NIC)

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

---UPDATE---

**   Database availability health check failed.
   Database copy: Mailbox Database 2004460567
   Redundancy count: 1

Error: There were database availability check failures for database 'Mailbox Database 2004460567' that may be lowering its availability. Availability Count: 1. Expected Availability Count: 2. Detailed error(s):

```
    winterfell:
    Database copy 'Mailbox Database 2004460567' is suspended on server 'winterfell'. Reason: None specified.. If you need to perform a switchover of this database, use the Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase cmdlet with the -SkipHealthChecks parameter.
```

================
   Full Copy Status
   ================

---

Database Copy : Mailbox Database 2004460567\winterfell

---

WorkerProcessId            : 9860
   ActivationPreference       : 1
   CopyStatus                 : Suspended
   Viable                     : False
   ActivationSuspended        : True
   ErrorEventId               : 0
   LastStatusTransitionTime   : 21/07/2016 16:48:01
   StatusRetrievedTime        : 22/07/2016 15:33:19
   InstanceStartTime          : 21/07/2016 16:48:01
   LowestLogPresent           : 0
   LastLogInspected           : 591
   LastLogReplayed            : 591
   LastLogCopied              : 591
   LastLogCopyNotified        : 591
   LastLogGenerated           : 683
   LastLogGeneratedTime       : 22/07/2016 15:33:19
   LastCopyNotifiedLogTime    : 21/07/2016 16:38:53
   LastInspectedLogTime       : 21/07/2016 16:38:53
   LastReplayedLogTime        : 21/07/2016 16:38:53
   LastCopiedLogTime          : 21/07/2016 16:38:53
   LastLogInfoFromClusterGen  : 683
   LastLogInfoFromClusterTime : 22/07/2016 15:33:09
   LastLogInfoFromCopierTime  : 21/07/2016 16:47:46
   LastLogInfoIsStale         : False
   ReplayLagEnabled           : Disabled
   ReplayLagPlayDownReason    : None
   ReplayLagPercentage        : 0

---

Database Copy : Mailbox Database 2004460567\helios

---

WorkerProcessId            : 3396
   ActivationPreference       : 2
   CopyStatus                 : Mounted
   Viable                     : False
   ActivationSuspended        : False
   ErrorEventId               : 0
   LastStatusTransitionTime   : 01/01/0001 00:00:00
   StatusRetrievedTime        : 22/07/2016 15:33:19
   InstanceStartTime          : 17/07/2016 15:42:07
   LowestLogPresent           : 1
   LastLogInspected           : 0
   LastLogReplayed            : 0
   LastLogCopied              : 0
   LastLogCopyNotified        : 683
   LastLogGenerated           : 683
   LastLogGeneratedTime       : 01/01/0001 00:00:00
   LastCopyNotifiedLogTime    : 22/07/2016 15:29:02
   LastInspectedLogTime       : 01/01/0001 00:00:00
   LastReplayedLogTime        : 01/01/0001 00:00:00
   LastCopiedLogTime          : 01/01/0001 00:00:00
   LastLogInfoFromClusterGen  : 683
   LastLogInfoFromClusterTime : 22/07/2016 15:33:09
   LastLogInfoFromCopierTime  : 22/07/2016 15:33:19
   LastLogInfoIsStale         : False
   ReplayLagEnabled           : Disabled
   ReplayLagPlayDownReason    : None
   ReplayLagPercentage        : 0

Comment: HI Aniga do you have a File Share Witness configured? if so where is it?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for coming back to me so quickly - the FSW is on a local server and we don't have a FSW on the cloud - should the FSW be on the cloud?

Comment: I can't help but think that there's probably more information available in the event logs. Have you looked at them?

Comment: @joeqwerty I went through the event log and can't seem to see anything that jumps out.

Comment: @joeqwerty The only error I have seen is updated on my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

A second NIC is not going to help unless you have a second connection to the off site server.

Do you have a domain controller in that data centre?

Where is your FSW?

Comment: Hi @Sembee , Thanks for coming back to be so quickly. Yes, we do have DC in that data centre and the FSW is on a local server.

Answer (score 0):

The errors indicate a database availability issue on your server. Follow these steps to fix the issue-

-**Make sure** (server 1): 192.168.0.20 & Winterfell (Server 2): can communicate with each other over the network. Check if firewall settings, routing, and any network ACLs is blocking the communication.

-**Ensure** antivirus or any third party software is compatible with Exchange server and not causing any issue.

-**Lack of disk space** is also leading the replication issues.

-**Examine log files** can give you more details for error messages or events.

-**Now Verify the** DAG configuration & check all servers have correct status.:

```
 Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -Status | fl
```

-**Verify the DAG** IP configuration to check networks are correctly configured, and the DAG IP is associated with the correct network.

```
 Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroupNetwork | fl
```

-**Check the status** of database copies using [Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus command](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-use-get-mailboxdatabasecopystatus-command/) for any errors or warnings

```
 Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Identity <DatabaseName>
```

-**Your error message** indicates that the database copy on the 'winterfell' server is suspended. Investigate the reason using following command:

```
 Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Identity <DatabaseName> | Format-List
```

-**If the issue occurs**, you need to dismount and repair the affected database. Make ensure you have a valid backup before attempting any database repair operations.